# Find prime numbers in a separate thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have been given an assignment that follows.

Write a multithreaded Java, Pthreads, or Win32 program that outputs prime numbers. This 
program should work as follows:

1. The user will run the program and will enter a number on the command line.
2. The program will then create a separate thread that outputs all the prime numbers 
   less than or equal to the number entered by the user.

---

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#define MAX_THREADS 1
using namespace std;

DWORD WINAPI Prime (LPVOID);
HANDLE hThreads [MAX_THREADS];
DWORD id [MAX_THREADS];
DWORD waiter;

DWORD WINAPI Prime(LPVOID Param)
{
    DWORD Number = *(DWORD*)Param;
    for (DWORD i=0;i<=Number;i++)
    {
        if((Number%2==0) ||(Number%3==0) || (Number%4==0)||(Number%5==0)||(Number%6==0)||  (Number%7==0)||(Number%8==0)||(Number%9==0))
        cout <<"";
        else
        cout<<i;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[ ])
{
    DWORD ThreadId;
    HANDLE ThreadHandle;
    int Param;

    cout<<"Enter a number:";
    cin>>Param;

    cout<<"Prime numbers less than and equal to your number";

    ThreadHandle=CreateThread(NULL,0,Prime,&Param,0,&ThreadId);

    waiter=WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS,hThreads,TRUE,INFINITE);

    for(int i=0;i<MAX_THREADS;i++)
        CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have been working on this program by using what I learned in class, but I cannot seem to get my program to work. If someone could please help me clean my program up and help me get it to work that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what it is that you program is doing (and/or not doing) that is different from what it should.  And comment your code!

Comment: I'd start by writing a single-threaded program that works, *then* deal with using threads to make that go faster.

Comment: Your program claims that a prime number is a number that isn't divisible with 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9. That's not quite the definition of a prime number. For instance, 2, 3, 5, and 7 are prime numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Because you check for divisibility by *all* integers between 2 and 9, your program will not report any primes less than 11.  And `i` is only used in the loop for printing purposes, and not used at all in looking for primes.

Comment: To be precise, the program will also report as a prime, any compound number made from primes greater than 7. E.g: 17*13. Or even 11^2.

Answer (score 0):

Your method of checking prime numbers is wrong! I added a function to check prime number

```
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #define MAX_THREADS 1
    using namespace std;
    DWORD WINAPI Prime (LPVOID);
    HANDLE hThreads [MAX_THREADS];
    DWORD id [MAX_THREADS];
    DWORD waiter;
    int check_prime(int a)
    {
       int c;
       for ( c = 2 ; c <= a - 1 ; c++ )
       { 
          if ( a%c == 0 )
            return 0;
       }
       if ( c == a )
          return 1;
    }
    DWORD WINAPI Prime(LPVOID Param)
    {
        DWORD Number = *(DWORD*)Param;
        for (DWORD i=2;i<=Number;i++)
        {
            if(check_prime(i)==0)
                cout <<"";
            else
                cout<<i;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    int main(int argc, char* argv[ ])
    {
        // same your code
        return 0;
    }
```